# Calling Twilio Voice API with Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, twilio, blazor

I am working on a project with blazor server and I am trying to make a voice call using Twilio.

I followed the documentation online from twilio for this to the letter but getting this error:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at QUBeMyGuest.Pages.GuestArrivals.EmergencyContact.GetClientToken() in C:\Pages\GuestArrivals\EmergencyContact.razor:line 98
   at QUBeMyGuest.Pages.GuestArrivals.EmergencyContact.OnAfterRenderAsync(Boolean firstRender) in C:\Users\\Pages\GuestArrivals\EmergencyContact.razor:line 58
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle)
```

The documentation stated that I should open a new asp.net core api project within my solution and add this class to the controller folder:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Twilio.Jwt;
using Twilio.Jwt.Client;
using Twilio.TwiML;
using Twilio.Types;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TwilioBackEndController : ControllerBase
    {
        public readonly string AccountSid = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        public readonly string AuthToken = "xxxxxxxx";
        public readonly string AppSid = "xxxxxxxx";
        public readonly string PhoneNumber = "xxxxxxxx";

        [HttpGet("token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetToken()
        {
            var scopes = new HashSet<IScope>
            {
                new OutgoingClientScope(AppSid),
                new IncomingClientScope("tester")
            };

            var capability = new ClientCapability(AccountSid, AuthToken, scopes: scopes);
            return await Task.FromResult(Content(capability.ToJwt(), "application/jwt"));
        }

        [HttpPost("voice")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostVoiceRequest([FromForm] string phone)
        {
            var destination = !phone.StartsWith('+') ? $"+{phone}" : phone;

            var response = new VoiceResponse();
            var dial = new Twilio.TwiML.Voice.Dial
            {
                CallerId = PhoneNumber
            };
            dial.Number(new PhoneNumber(destination));

            response.Append(dial);

            return await Task.FromResult(Content(response.ToString(), "application/xml"));
        }
    }
}
```

I then set up the page to make the call with my blazor project

```
@page "/guest/emergencycall"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
@inject HttpClient httpClient
@using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
@using System.Net.Http


<EditForm Model="Input" OnValidSubmit="InitiatePhoneCall">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <ValidationSummary />

    <p>
        <label for="phoneNumber">Enter Phone Number:</label>
        <InputText id="phoneNumber" @bind-Value="Input.PhoneNumber"></InputText>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsDialDisabled">DIAL</button>
        <button type="button" id="endBtn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsEndDisabled" @onclick="EndPhoneCall">END</button>
        <button type="button" id="clearBtn" class="btn btn-primary" disabled="@IsClearDisabled" @onclick="ClearPhoneNumber">CLEAR</button>
    </p>
</EditForm>

<hr />

@if (Logs.Count == 0)
{
    <p>No Logs available yet</p>
}
else
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var log in Logs)
        {

            <li>@log</li>
        }
    </ul>
}

@code {
    private string _tokenUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    private bool appSetupRun = false;

    protected bool IsDialDisabled { get; set; } = false;
    protected bool IsEndDisabled { get { return !IsDialDisabled; } }

    protected bool IsClearDisabled { get { return string.IsNullOrEmpty(Input.PhoneNumber); } }
    protected List<string> Logs { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    protected InputModel Input { get; set; } = new InputModel();
    [Inject]
    protected IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }
    [Inject]
    protected IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender && !appSetupRun)
        {
            var token = await GetClientToken();
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.setup", token);
            appSetupRun = true;
        }
    }

    protected async Task InitiatePhoneCall()
    {
        IsDialDisabled = true;
        await LogMessage($"Calling the number {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.placeCall", Input.PhoneNumber);
        await LogMessage($"Called the number {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    protected async Task EndPhoneCall()
    {
        IsDialDisabled = false;
        await LogMessage($"Ending the call to {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("appFunctions.endCall");
        await LogMessage($"Ended the call to {Input.PhoneNumber}");
        StateHasChanged();

    }

    protected async Task ClearPhoneNumber()
    {
        await LogMessage("Clearing the phone number entry");
        Input.PhoneNumber = string.Empty;
        await LogMessage("Cleared the phone number entry");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async Task<string> GetClientToken()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(_tokenUrl);

        using var client = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    [JSInvokable]
    public async Task LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Logs.Add($"{DateTimeOffset.Now} - {message}");
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Phone(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your phone number in a proper format")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then added this JS function:

```
window.appFunctions = {
    setup: function (token) {
        console.log('Getting connected');

        // Setup Twilio Device
        Twilio.Device.setup(token);

        Twilio.Device.ready(() => {
            console.log('We are connected and ready to do the thing');
        });

        Twilio.Device.error((err) => {
            console.error('This should not have been reached. We need to do something here');
            console.error(err);
        });
    },
    placeCall: function (destination) {
        console.log(`Calling ${destination}`);
        Twilio.Device.connect({ phone: destination });
        console.log(`Successfully called ${destination}`);
    },
    endCall: function () {
        console.log('Ending the call');
        Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
        console.log('Successfully ended the call');
    }
};
```

in my startup file I then added this, but doesn't seem to have made a difference:

```
 services.AddHttpClient();

            if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient)))
            {
                services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
                {
                    var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
                    return new HttpClient
                    {
                        BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
                    };
                });
            }
```

Any suggestions on what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When seeing a 404, the first thing that should come to mind is an incorrect URL. Since the 404 is coming from GetClientToken in your razor file. That means your _tokenUrl is probably incorrect. Looking at your controller, your URL should look something like https://{host}/token/. It's possible that you hardcoded the link in the documentation, meanwhile, it's supposed to be based on your controller.

PS: HTTP 404 means that the requested resource cannot be found. Get familiar with other HTTP response codes too, might save you a ton of debugging.

Comment: I have to use a Ngrok tunnel for the api project. So What I have in _tokenUrl is ```https://4b4cjkaaf1b.ngrok.io/api/twiliobackend``` (api is thename of the asp project) I also then have this address stored in the Twilio dashboard

Comment: From your controller, your URL should look more like this: 
 https://4b4cjkaaf1b.ngrok.io/api/twillobackend/token

 Notice the route set on top of your GetToken action in your controller.

PS: When a string is passed as an argument into an HttpMethod attribute like 'HttpGet'. The string serves as a route. It becomes an equivalent of the 'Route' attribute

Comment: yes thank you that was the issue this now works for me. However I am having another issue..I can go in and make the phone call but then I click on another section of the app and then go back into the emergency contact page I am getting this error: ```Error: Microsoft.JSInterop.JSException: Cannot read property 'setToken' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'setToken' of undefined
    ``` If I automatically refresh the page then everything is ok. Is there a something I should be doing that can refresh the page when i go into it for a second time?

Comment: This error is outside the scope of the code you posted. Is your code hosted on Github?

Comment: No I don't have it on github. So there error is something else and not in the code?

Comment: The error is definitely in the code, I'm just saying that you didn't post that part of the code